# Join to display spesific data in query builder laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have 2 table in database

[image]
[image]

In laravel I used query builder like this

```
DB::table('chart')->join('chart_detail', 'chart.id', '=', 'chart_detail.id_cart')->get();
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

It's not what I want to display data, because too much redundancy
I want to display data like this:

[image]

Where I'm wrong in join sql command?

Comment: this is not a sql problem

Comment: @Fabricator hm would you mind give me clue how to solve it?

Comment: after getting the query result, you can do the merging in PHP

Comment: @Fabricator thanks...i found it now :D

Comment: It would be helpful to share how you fixed it here.

Comment: @davejal actually i still not solve it, i will share it later if already solved :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can do with your query exactly... on your front-end you can group it together by doing something like this (better to use a customer id if you have one):

```
$data = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if (!isset($data[ $row['nama_customer'] ])) {
        $data[ $row['nama_customer'] ] = [];
    }
    $data[ $row['nama_customer'] ][] = $row;
}
var_dump($data);
```

Then when you render your HTML you have enough information to group it together by setting rowspan on your `<tr>` tag.

Comment: hm how to access `nama_customer` in `$data`...i tried with something like this `$data[0]['nama_customer]`....it's show error `Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: if just `$data['nama_customer]` it's show error `Undefined index: nama_customer`

Comment: Do a `var_dump` to inspect the contents.  It is a hash based array, you can access it by the customer name, e.g., `var_dump($data['customer1'])` -- important: it would be better if you change the code to use the customer id for the key instead since the id number is always unique.