# Grouping result query in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a result table like this (left table)

[image]
[image]

I want it to become like (right table)

In my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521949/join-to-display-spesific-data-in-query-builder-laravel),

**@Clayton** has already provide answer how to do it in php laravel (grouped in front end)

```
$data = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
   if (!isset($data[ $row['nama_customer'] ])) {
      $data[ $row['nama_customer'] ] = [];
   }
   $data[ $row['nama_customer'] ][] = $row;
}
var_dump($data);
```

but for some reason now I need to make it in ajax 
I already try something like this

```
$.post('myurl', {id:id} , function(result) {

   var data = []; var idcustomer;
   for (x in result) {
      idcustomer = result[x]['id_customer'];

      if(typeof( data[idcustomer] ) != "undefined" && data[idcustomer] !== null)
          data[idCustomer] = [];

      data[idCustomer][] = data[x];
   }

   console.log(data);

});
```

I think I already solved isset function with that code
but when I find 2 dimensional array I get confused

can someone give me an idea of how to do it in ajax

---

**@Solved**

```
function groupedTable() {
        var seen = []; var a = 0;

        $('#mytable td:first-child').each(function() 
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var index = $this.index();
            var txt =  $this.text();

            if (seen[index] === txt) 
            {
                $($this.parent().prev().children()[index]).attr('rowspan', a);
                $this.hide();
            }
            else {
                seen[index] = txt;
                a = countLoop(txt, $this);
            }
        });
      }

      function countLoop(txt) {
        var span = 0;

        $('#mytable td:first-child').each(function()  
        {
            $this = $(this);
            var txt1 =  $this.text();

            if (txt1 == txt) 
               span++;
        });

        return span;
      }
```

Comment: if you have already solved it in backend why not send the required format in json from backend itself like `{customer1: {[item1: 3], [item2: 3] ..}, customer2: {[..]}}`

Comment: @RaunakKathuria sory my explanation not clear...it's not in backend, but i grouped it in front end but with php way to display data

Comment: Can you clarifying one thing the result table you have is html response from ajax or are you getting result as json?

Comment: @RaunakKathuria hmm..because i don't set specify response in `$.post`, i think `$.post` default response is `xml`...correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                function MergeCommonRows(table, columnIndexToMerge) {
                    previous = null;
                    cellToExtend = null;
                    table.find("td:nth-child(" + columnIndexToMerge + ")").each(function() {
                        jthis = $(this);
                        content = jthis.text() if (previous == content) {
                            jthis.remove();
                            if (cellToExtend.attr("rowspan") == undefined) {
                                cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", 2);
                            } else {
                                currentrowspan = parseInt(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan"));
                                cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", currentrowspan + 1);
                            }
                        } else {
                            previous = content;
                            cellToExtend = jthis;
                        }
                    });
                };
                MergeCommonRows($("#aTable"), 1);
            }
</script>
```

Comment: in that link take that code and do manually you will get the output.

Comment: this code give me idea how to solve it....the idea is so simple use ajax to populate table and call grouped function after data is populated.... I modify a lot of this script to get result like i want ...forget to accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve by jquery. refer the below url and call the MergeCommonRows function inside body tag it will work

```
function MergeCommonRows(table, columnIndexToMerge){ previous = null; cellToExtend = null; table.find("td:nth-child("+columnIndexToMerge+")").each(function(){ jthis = $(this); content = jthis.text() if(previous == content){ jthis.remove(); if(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan") == undefined){ cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", 2); } else{ currentrowspan = parseInt(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan")); cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", currentrowspan+1); } } else{ previous = content; cellToExtend = jthis; } }); };
```